# NO PUEDO USAR ARCHIVOS CSS EN DJANGO

Tags: python, css, html5, django, django-urls

**AYUDAAAA, ESTOY HACE DÍAS INTENTANDO SOLUCIONAR ESTO PERO NADA, ABAJO LES DEJO EL ENLACE GITHUB CON TODO EL CÓDIGO**

**SI LO DESCARGARON Y LES FUNCIONÓ TODO, TAMBIÉN COMENTEN, PUEDE QUE SEA UN PROBLEMA DE MI VERSIÓN O ALGO ASÍ**

Quiero agregar un enlace de archivos css con Django, pero no funciona, usé lo de `staticfiles` y no me funciona, sólo muestra el html sin estilos, acá dejo como estan organizados los archivos y el código modificado, espero puedan ayudarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ARCHIVO** `static/css/estilos.css`

```
p{
    background-color:darkblue;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**ARCHIVO** `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/estilos.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    
    <p>PRUEBA DJANGO</p>

</body>

</html>
```

**ARCHIVO** `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def funcion(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

**ARCHIVO** `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from miPaginaweb.views import funcion

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pagina/', funcion)
]
```

**ARCHIVO** `settings.py` (parte static de settings)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),)
```

**DEJO EL ENLACE GITHUB DE TODO EL PAQUETE** https://github.com/KodingT/Django_problema

Answer (score 1):

Te diría que intentaras utilizando el siguiente código en tu settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
.
.
.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]
```

Comment: Acabo de ponerlo, pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Dentro de INSTALLED_APPS ¿ se encuentra django.contrib.staticfiles ?

Comment: Lo acabo de revisar y sí se encuentra "django.contrib.staticfiles"

Comment: Acabo de crear un proyecto nuevo con la información que has agregado anteriormente y corre perfectamente , por lo tanto no se en donde difiere la carga de static,  lamento no a ver podido ayudarte .

Comment: Lo ultimo que te diría que intentaras , seria revisar si tienes configurado en settings.py , la sección de templates

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el error esta en urls
proba de poner esto

path('pagina/', views.funcion, name='funcion')

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).